# One variable for different collections in Jekyll to use in forloop

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have several collections on my Jekyll site. I've added post navigation to one of the collections displaying a counter on each post page:

```
{% assign testimonials = site.testimonials %}
{% assign page_order = 1 %}
{% for node in testimonials reversed %}
  {% if node.url == page.url %}
    {{ page_order }} from {{ forloop.length }}
  {% else %}
    {% assign page_order = page_order | plus: 1 %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I would like to make this code work not only for `site.testimonials`, but for other collections as well. I tried to pass a variable for collections like this:

```
{% capture label %}{{ page.collection }}{% endcapture %}
{% assign collection = site.collections | where: "label",label | first %}
{% for node in collection reversed %}
  {% if node.url == page.url %}
    {{ page_order }} from {{ forloop.length }}
  {% else %}
    {% assign page_order = page_order | plus: 1 %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any way to pass a variable for all collections in Jekyll to use in forloop in post navigation?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: @wasthishelpful the second code above doesn't work. I have only empty spaces for page_order and forloop.length. I guess, it can't find the corresponding collection with the page.label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access collection with `site.testimonials`, you get collection's documents array.

```
{{ site.testimonials | inspect }}

# output >> [#<Jekyll::Document ...>, #<Jekyll::Document ...>, ...]
```

When you access a collection while looping over site.collection, you receive the collection's object :

```
{% assign collection = site.collections | where: "label",page.collection | first %}
{{ collection | inspect }}
# output >> { "output": true, "label": "collectionLabel", 
              "docs": [ doc1, docs2, ... ], "files": [], 
              "directory": "/path/to/collection", 
              "relative_directory": "_colectionDirectory" }
```

In your case, you just have to replace :

```
{% for node in collection reversed %}
```

By :

```
{% for node in collection.docs reversed %}
```